# Applying ntile over nested tibbles

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to apply `ntile` over some nested tibbles but I cannot seem to get it working.

Can you see where I am going wrong?

```
data(iris)

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(quintile = ntile(Petal.Length, 5)) # This works

nested_iris <- iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>%
  mutate(quintile = map(data, ~ntile(.x, Petal.Length, 5))) #This doesn`t work
```

Answer (score 3):

Place the `ntile` inside a `mutate` call and update the 'data' to create a new column inside it.  It may be better to minimize the storage structure

```
library(tidyverse)
o1 <- iris %>%
        as_tibble() %>%
        group_by(Species) %>%
        nest(.key = "data") %>% 
        mutate(data = map(data, ~ 
         .x %>% 
           mutate(quintile = ntile(Petal.Length, 5))))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Species    data             
#  <fct>      <list>           
#1 setosa     <tibble [50 × 5]>
#2 versicolor <tibble [50 × 5]>
#3 virginica  <tibble [50 × 5]>
```

NOTE: Assuming that the OP need all the columns with the additional 'quintile'.

Then, we `unnest`

```
o1 %>%
    unnest
# A tibble: 150 x 6
#   Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width quintile
#   <fct>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>    <int>
# 1 setosa           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2        2
# 2 setosa           4.9         3            1.4         0.2        2
# 3 setosa           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2        1
# 4 setosa           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2        3
# 5 setosa           5           3.6          1.4         0.2        2
# 6 setosa           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4        5
# 7 setosa           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3        2
# 8 setosa           5           3.4          1.5         0.2        3
# 9 setosa           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2        2
#10 setosa           4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1        3
# … with 140 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about a double `mutate` function. It seems to keep all of the information inside the `quintile` list also!

Answer (score 2):

you need a `transmute` or `mutate` inside `map`:

```
nested_iris <- iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>%
  mutate(quintile = map(data, ~transmute(.x, quantile = ntile(Petal.Length, 5))))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    data              quintile         
  <fct>      <list>            <list>           
1 setosa     <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 1]>
2 versicolor <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 1]>
3 virginica  <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 1]>
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution the only problem is that the `quintile` loses all the other columns, i.e. its a `50 x 1` list. using `unnest(nested_iris)` solves this issue though.

Comment: the other columns are still contained in `data`. I used `transmute` instead of `mutate` to not have the remaining columns twice. 
If you want all columns in the column use `mutate` instead of `transmute`.

Comment: @user113156  You can simply use `nested_iris %>% unnest` will unnest both the columns.  The only difference in Cett's solution and mine is that his solution have two columns, and you may have the option to select `Species`, `quntile`, and then get a two column data.frame after unnesting while in my solution, it is always the full dataset.  I did that because of the storage space

Comment: I see! I replaced your line with this: `mutate(quintile = map(data, ~mutate(.x, quantile = ntile(Petal.Length, 5))))` and it worked great!