# nesting tibbles, perform operation, unnest and nest data in a different form

Tags: r

This is a follow on question to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971458/applying-ntile-over-nested-tibbles/55971525?noredirect=1#comment98594268_55971525). I am looking to take it a bit futher but not sure how.

What I want to do is extract the quintiles for each `Sepal_width`, `Petal_width` etc. and store them as a nested tibble.

Instead of `Species` I actually have time series data of years (so I nest on these years), so I actually want to calculate the quintile of a number of columns in that year (as opposed to `Sepal.length` etc.) and then pull out all quintiles of `1` for all years, combine them into one time series data frame for all years and then nest them back based on quintiles.

I know the title might be a little confusion so what I am trying to do is:

1) Nest the data by "year/(species)"

2) Compute the quintiles for a number of columns

3) unnest the data where all quintiles equal 1, then 2, then 3... etc. so all the years/(species) are put back into a total of 5 data frames (or hopefully new nested tibbles)

4) Renest the data by quintiles (which now contains all the years / (species)

So I will have a nested tibble of 5 tibbles (one for each quintile) where each tibble consists of all the years (species) combined back together

Data:

```
data(iris)

iris_quintiles <- iris %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest(.key = "data") %>% 
  mutate(Sep_len = map(data, ~select(.x, Species, Sepal.Length)),
         Sep_len = map(Sep_len, ~mutate(.x, quantile_Sep_len = ntile(Sepal.Length, 5))),
         Sep_wid = map(data, ~select(.x, Species, Sepal.Width)),
         Sep_wid = map(Sep_wid, ~mutate(.x, quantile_Sep_wid = ntile(Sepal.Width, 5))),
         Pet_len = map(data, ~select(.x, Species, Petal.Length)),
         Pet_len = map(Pet_len, ~mutate(.x, quantile_Pet_len = ntile(Petal.Length, 5))),
         Pet_wid = map(data, ~select(.x, Species, Petal.Width)),
         Pet_wid = map(Pet_wid, ~mutate(.x, quantile_Pet_wid = ntile(Petal.Width, 5))))

iris_quintiles

# Here is where it gets a little messy and what I am currently doing
# is extracting them individually but I will have to do this for quantile_Sen_len, quantile_Pet_len, quantile_Pet_wid etc. where the code gets quite large

df1 <- iris_quintiles %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(quantile_Sep_len == 1)


df2 <- iris_quintiles %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(quantile_Sep_len == 2)


df3 <- iris_quintiles %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(quantile_Sep_len == 3)


df <- list(df1, df2, df3)

df <- plyr::ldply(df, data.frame)


df %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest(.key = "data")
```

Expected Output: - Not "exactly" but more or less close.

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  QUINTILES    data              Sep_len           Sep_wid           Pet_len           Pet_wid          
  <fct>      <list>            <list>            <list>            <list>            <list>           
1 quintile_1     <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 5]>
2 quintile_2 <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 5]>
3 quintile_3  <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 5]>
3 quintile_4  <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 5]>
3 quintile_5  <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 4]> <tibble [50 x 5]>
```

Ignore the tibble sizes since I copied and pasted this tibble and modified it a bit.

So there is 5 tibbles - one for each quantile. The `sep_len`, `sep_wid`, `pet_len` and `pet_wid` consists of all the data (for all Species) - i.e. before the nested tibble nested on `Species` - performed the quintile operation and then using something like this

`df1 <- iris_quintiles %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(quantile_Sep_len == 1)`

allowed me to extract the quintile = 1 for all 3 species. So here `df1` should basically be `Sep_len` in the above tibble for `quintile_1`. The following:

`df2 <- iris_quintiles %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(quantile_Sep_len == 2)`

would be `sep_len` for `quintile_2` in the same tibble.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really don't understand.  I think it might be simpler if you started with the result you want rather than the process you think you should use to get there.  Meaning show us actually what you want not the last step of the code you think you want.

Comment: I fully understand that its a little confusing! Using the Sepal data example. I want to nest the data by `Species` then perform a quintile operation for each of the `Sepal.length`, p Sepal.width`, `Petal.length`, `Petal.width`. So for each `Species` I will have the quintiles for each of the 4 mentioned variables. I want to then pull the data where `Petal.length == 1` combine this with all 3 `Species` into a single data frame. Do this for all 5 quintiles. Then nest the data back together based on these quintiles.

Comment: @user113156  Is the last code block your expect3ed output

Comment: I will take a look now!

Comment: I added an "Expected Output" part to the original question.

Comment: @user113156  Are you saying that `iris_quintiles` calculation is wrong?

Comment: You are a massive help. In your answer below the `out` has 3 tibbles `setosa`, `versicolor` and `virginica`. I am trying to make the tibbles `quintile_1`, `quintile_2`, `quintile_3`,  `quintile_4` and `quintile_5`. Where the columns will be `sep_len`, `sep_wid`, `pet_len` and `pet_wid` which was caluclated in these lines of code `Sep_len = map(Sep_len, ~mutate(.x, quantile_Sep_len = ntile(Sepal.Length, 5)))`. So in the nested tibble row 1 `quintile_1` and column 1 `Sep_len` will consist of all the `Species` who had a "Sepal_length" of 1.

Comment: thanks, but my confusion is whether you calcualted 'iris_qunitiles' correctly.  In that case, I can skip those part

Comment: Yes as far as I am aware the `iris_quintiles` is claculated correctly. Its an adapted version of a previous question you helped me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971458/applying-ntile-over-nested-tibbles/55971525?noredirect=1#comment98594268_55971525

Comment: Not sure you would get 50 x4, should it be 30 x4 `map(names(iris_quintiles)[-(1:2)], ~  iris_quintiles %>% select(Species, .x) %>% unnest %>% rename_at(vars(matches("quantile")), ~ "QUINTILES") %>% group_by(QUINTILES = str_c("quintile_", QUINTILES)) %>% nest(.key = !!.x)) %>% reduce(inner_join, by = "QUINTILES")`

Comment: In each column, the frequency of quintiles is 30. please check `map(names(iris_quintiles)[-(1:2)], ~  
       iris_quintiles %>% 
         select(Species, .x) %>%
         unnest %>% rename_at(vars(matches("quantile")), ~ "QUINTILES") %>% count(QUINTILES) )`

Comment: OHHH are you asking what quintile each observation is in?

Comment: Are you writing it so you can have an unknown number of total observations and where the number in each species must be the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could loop over the column names of 'iris_quintiles', `unnest`, then `nest` and `reduce` it to a single dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
map(names(iris_quintiles)[-(1:2)], ~  
       iris_quintiles %>% 
         select(Species, .x) %>%
         unnest %>% 
         rename_at(vars(matches("quantile")), ~ "QUINTILES") %>%
         group_by(QUINTILES = str_c("quintile_", QUINTILES)) %>% 
         nest(.key = !!.x)) %>% 
         reduce(inner_join, by = "QUINTILES") %>% 
         arrange(factor(QUINTILES, levels = str_c("quintile_", 1:5)))
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks exactly what I want. I will apply it to my actual data and let you know how it goes but it looks correct. One question, why do you think the `quintiles` calculation is wrong?

Comment: @user113156 I didn't look at the calculation, so I just wanted to make sure that the part is correct and focus on the expected output